# How to pub serve in sublime?

Tags: dart, sublimetext3

Saving pubspec.yaml runs pub get, and hitting F7 'runs' the project, not sure what that means but it doesn't seem to do much. How do I pub serve?

Answer (score 1):

The document says if the file is in the `web` directory, <kbd>F7</kbd> runs it via `pub serve`. This should launch Dartium and load the file from the launched `pub serve`.

https://github.com/guillermooo/dart-sublime-bundle/wiki/Running-Files#primary-action

On my system the default configuration didn't contain build variants for Linux (only Windows and OSX)

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 - when I press F7, it just tells me it is 'running' the project, but nothing happens. Dartium doesn't open so I do it manually and try to connect but I get nothing for Localhost:8080

Comment: Can you please report the issue in the plugin GitHub repo. How does the directory structure of your project look like?